# RecyclerView adapter `onCreateViewHolder` & `onBindViewHolder` invoked only once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a **RecyclerView.Adapter** like this:

```
internal class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
  private val data: List<MyModel> = SeedData().seed()

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(v: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val binding = MyListitemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(v.context), v, false)
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
  }

  override fun getItemCount() = data.size

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(data[position])
  }
}
```

However, only the first item from the **data** is getting displayed (i.e. **onCreateViewHolder** & **onBindViewHolder** invoked only one time).  How can I make it display all items from the data properly?

Comment: So the `data.size` is not returning `1`, it's returning some number which is more that one - is that right?

Comment: There is a chance that your RecyclerView height is too small.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Correct, data has multiple items.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That would explain why `onBindViewHolder` gets called only once?

Comment: or maybe your item layout height is match_parent

Comment: @moumenShobakey Does that effect `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: As i remember yes , i always face this problem

Comment: Yes, @moumenShobakey is right. If you try to scroll then you can see that it invoke `onBindViewHolder` again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commented answers above are correct.  My list item (views) were full height of screen:
[image]

This means that RecyclerView would only update the ViewHolder once you scroll to the next element.  The solution is to modify the height of these items.